Convincing the contrapositive is equivalent
To prove that $a \Rightarrow b$, we can equivalently prove
$\neg{b} \Rightarrow \neg{a}$.

Q. How can we best explain this to the student?

Here's my attempt.

Suppose we prove that $\neg{b} \Rightarrow \neg{a}$,
and that $a$ holds. Then it cannot be that $\neg{b}$ holds,
because $\neg{b} \Rightarrow \neg{a}$, contradicting that $a$ holds.
So if $a$ holds, $b$ must hold.
Which proves that $a \Rightarrow b$.

I would appreciate arguments more convincing to the student. I feel my
logic is too formal for most students.

Same structure, but with examples? (I'd use math examples...)

@SueVanHattum: I don't like relying on formal logic. Better something that is immediately convincing because of an ideal example...

“Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.” - Sherlock Homes…Arthur Conan Doyle

Following the comment by @user52817, you can write down a truth table for both and see that both are eliminating the possibility that a is true and b is not.

Similar to @MichałMiśkiewicz's comment, is there a reason why you cannot use a truth table to show this? That is, make a 5 x 4 table where the top row contains "$a$", "$b$", "$a \implies b$", and "$\neg b \implies \neg a$" in the 4 columns. Then, do the following: (1) fill in the 1st column below "$a$" with "T" (true), "T", "F" (false), "F", (2) fill in the 2nd column below "$b$" with "T", "F", "T", "F", (3) fill in the 3rd and 4th columns based on the definitions of "$a \implies b$" and "$\neg b \implies \neg a$". The students should then see that the 3rd and 4th columns are exactly the same.

@mhdadk: When teaching logic, I use truth tables; very effective. Here I am trying to avoid that formality, and instead achieve gut-acceptance of the equivalence.

Be careful about relying only on gut-acceptance.  Ideally, your students should be able to pass the Wason Selection Task.

Isn't the issue not that your explanation is too formal, but that your students aren't going to understand any explanation, because they lack the sophistication and also you are teaching them something else?  Just leave contrapositive as a proof rule they need to memorise and show a few examples.

Sometimes, examples are the best explanation, and this is such a case. I think it's because the underlying idea is already understood by most people, even those who haven't studied math and logic.
The examples are easy to construct. "If I'm in Kentucky, then I'm in America" is equivalent to "If I'm not in America, then I'm not in Kentucky." And "If I'm in Turkey, then I'm in Asia" is equivalent to "If I'm not in Asia, then I'm not in Turkey" which are both false, with the same counterexample (European part of Istanbul). You can do mathematical examples, too.
I guess one other thing that can go wrong is if students are shaky on the idea of what the contrapositive is. You can clear that up by having them drill some problems of the form "find the contrapositive of these statements:"

I think most students would be convinced of the feasibility of the rule by such examples. +1

I up-voted this answer because it's pragmatic and it works. There is one problem that bothers me though. We spend so much time teaching students that "examples are not proof," yet many students (even at the college level) still have a hard time with that. I think it can sometimes be self-defeating when the teachers start to use examples in place of proof. For that reason, I think the Venn diagram approach suggested by @templatetypedef is also worth a try. Then use specific examples to illustrate the Venn diagrams.

@SyntaxJunkie It's true that examples aren't proof, but the question (as I understood it) was about how to get the intuition across. One can of course show students a rigorous proof in addition to the examples.

I think this is best even without the negative examples. Positive examples are enough, and negative examples are confusing.

Just be careful.  You can be in Turkey and not in Asia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Thrace

Kentucky $\Rightarrow$ America is a convincing example---Thanks!

@guesttroll Wasn't that the point?

Will, maybe.  But I'd like to see the edit history off that answer.  Can't access it for some reason.  It's possible, I skimmed too fast, but I seem to remember it different (and there is a day ago edit now).

It just occurred to me that territories on a map are a physical Venn diagram, arguably the first subconscious inspiration for those to follow.

A few options I’ve found useful when explaining this in my own courses. These are more about building intuition for why they’re equivalent than formally proving they’re equivalent. I usually do a two-pass approach of first building the intuition, then later going back and showing the formal logic once it’s had time to sit for a bit.

Draw a Venn diagram showing, schematically, what $a \Rightarrow b$ means: have a bubble of “times when $a$ is true” surrounded by a bubble of “times when $b$ is true.” Then point out that this same diagram has the following property: if $b$ is false, you’re outside the larger bubble, and thus outside the inner bubble. That means $a$ must be false. So the diagram is also what you’d draw for $\lnot b \Rightarrow \lnot a$.

I’m based in the US where the minimum drinking age is 21. We can express the drinking age law as the implication $\text{Drinks} \Rightarrow \text{Is21}$. Now imagine you’re at a bar and want to make sure that the drinking age law is being respected. There are two ways you could do this. First, you could find everyone who’s drinking and confirm that they’re all at least 21. Second, you could find everyone who’s under 21 and make sure they’re not drinking. These are equivalent ways to assess this implication. The former is the original implication. The latter is the contrapositive $\lnot \text{Is21} \Rightarrow \lnot \text{Drinks}$.

A student has arrived at college and their father makes them promise “if something bad happens, call me!” The student agrees. Three weeks later, the father starts getting anxious because they haven’t heard anything from their child. But the mother pipes up and says “hey, don’t worry about it. They promised you they’d call if something bad happens. So since they haven’t called, nothing bad has happened.”

A colleague of mine truthfully made the following promise to her students: if you submit a perfect March Madness bracket, I’ll give you an A+. At the end of the quarter, a student earns an A-. What can we infer from this? Well, among other things, they must not have turned in a perfect March Madness bracket. And indeed my colleague has promised everyone that if they don’t earn an A+, they must have not predicted the full bracket correctly.



I had just been about to suggest the Venn/Euler diagram — if formal derivations fail to convince for looking too complicated, I feel this method is overall best thanks to its paucity of moving parts. Smaller interior (i.e., the region depicting the truth-set for $a$ is enclosed within that for $b$) means larger exterior, and vice versa

Here's a semi-formalish way that doesn't rely on "argument from example", but also doesn't rely on intuitionless proofs or truth tables.
Observe that if true and false are represented by 1 and 0 respectively, then $a \Rightarrow b$ is equivalent to $a \le b$. If $a$ is 1 then $b$ must also be 1, but if $a$ is 0 then $b$ could be either 0 or 1. Or, "$b$ is at least as true as $a$".
Then of the negations, we can write $1 - b \le 1 - a$. This follows from the direction of the inequality being reversed when both sides are multiplied by −1. And this is the contrapositive. The derivation also works in reverse, showing that they are logically equivalent.

This is very cool. I think probably I would end up making truth tables anyway to convince people that "$a \to b$ is equivalent to $a \leq b$" but it is still neat.

Bring a bicycle into class. Statement $a$ is "Pedals moving forward." Statement $b$ is "Wheel moves forward." Then $a \Rightarrow b$. Interpret negation as "moving backward" (yes, technically not the true negation).
Show them how you can have $\lnot a \land b$ (pedaling backwards while moving forward, a popular thing to do) so that does not violate the implication. So $\lnot a$ does not imply $\lnot b$.
Finally, pick up the rear end a bit so that the tire is off the floor and rotate the wheel backwards. The pedals will also start moving backward. Ta-da! The contrapositive.

I think the truth value of the converse of the statement (i.e, wheel moving forward $ \Rightarrow$ pedals move forward) is not going to be entirely obvious to people who don't ride bikes.  user1149748's examples strike me as a bit clearer.

This example appears to demonstrate that the contrapositive is sometimes, but not always, implied by the original conditional statement. Of course, the problem is the incorrect negation. Overall I think this would be more confusing than enlightening, and might introduce misconceptions about negation too.

In addition to giving real-world examples, as suggested in other answers, I would also (make it an exercise) write down the truth tables for ⇒,  and ¬⇒¬ respectively, and observe that they are equal.

Suggestion
First, establish the removal of double negation as well as the commutativity of conjunction.
Then make use of the definition:

$P\implies Q~~\equiv~~\neg(P \land \neg Q)~~~$ for any propositions
$P$ and $Q$

EDIT: To justify this definition, suppose that from "P is true" we can infer that "Q is true." This rules out only the possibility that both "P is true" and "Q is false." Symbolically, we have: $\neg (P\land \neg Q).$ It should be pointed out to students that  P implies Q does not mean that P causes Q, e.g. "It is raining implies that it is cloudy" does not mean that rain causes cloudiness. It means that we can only rule out the possibility that, at the moment, it is raining and not cloudy.
Then we have:
$A\implies B~~~ \equiv~~~\neg(A \land \neg B)$
$\neg B \implies \neg A ~~~\equiv~~~\neg(\neg B \land \neg\neg A)~~~\equiv ~~~\neg(\neg B \land A)~~~\equiv ~~~ \neg(A \land \neg B)~~~\equiv~~~ A\implies B  $

Please note that the last sentence in OP's question is "I feel my logic is too formal for most students."

@JochenGlueck In the unlikely event that students won't settle for a few "cooked-up" examples to demonstrate the feasibility of the rule, only a formal proof would suffice.

Although I agree it's not answering OP's question as it is, the answer makes some points important even in a non-rigorous context. 1) An implication is nothing but eliminating one possibility (that $P$ holds and $Q$ doesn't). 2) If you understand it this way, it's obvious that $A \implies B$ and $\neg B \implies \neg A$ "are saying the same thing" (see the comments under OP for a similar point).

Moreover, point 1) is useful if one wants to teach some logic around implications. Students are often intuitively opposed to the convention that $A \implies B$ is considered true if neither $A$ or $B$ hold, so stressing 1) might help them remember this.
